# How to prepare Rainfall erosivity map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I am trying to develop rainfall erosivity map over a study area using 30yrs period rainfall data. i have determined the rainfall erosivity R for each year, how do i use this to prepare a map showing the rainfall erosivity for the entire study area. Data was collected from a single location which and the elevation. How do i put these together and extrapolate rain fall erosivity over a 15000ha area

Comment: You only have one erosivity value for the entire study area?

Comment: As @HasanMustafa mentioned, spatial interpolation of data with only one value will be quite pointless. Do you want to show temporal change? Maybe add a sketch of what you would like to do, or explain the problem a little more detailed, please.

Comment: I have summarized rainfall erosvity for every month in a year and for every year for the 30yrs. I also have the coordinates of the rain gauge and its elevation

Comment: I want to prepare erosivity map for the study area using the RUSLE equation and one of the inputs is rainfall erosivity which i was hope to generate from the rainfall data. There are several approaches to deriving rainfall erosivity but i am using one using erosive rainfall to determine the Rvalue

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Collect data at more locations and corresponding lng/lat coordinates
2. [Make XY Event layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm) (in-memory point layer) from the lng/lat coordinates
3. Use [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm) to create a point layer
4. Use [Project](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/project.htm) tool to re-project data from WGS 1984 to a more local projection
5. Use an [interpolation method](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/understanding-interpolation-analysis.htm) to create a raster surface for a given year dataset

Comment: There is only one central station for rainfall data in my study area and that was where i got the data from and this spans 30yr period from 1971 to 2012, in fact this is all i have

Comment: The challenge with the question as stated is since you have data for one location it cannot be interpolated spatially out for an area like 15000ha.  There are ways in GIS to show graphically changes in symbols or color of symbols for each year at the same location, but that would be a new question or an edit to this question to open up that conversation.

Comment: i will want to look at all available options to see what i can do with the data

Comment: I now have data from 6 different stations within the study site, which i used to derive rainfall erosivity values for between 40-11years period. I used the addxy coordinates tool to locate the raingages in a map and using the feature to feature tool in arcmap converted the processed data in excel into a feature. I tried using the Spline approach to interpolate the erosivity values to cover the entire site, but what i am getting is not what i want. How do i improve it. I am attaching two maps for clarification

Comment: @dru87 -  I now have data from 6 different stations within the study site, which i used to derive rainfall erosivity values for between 40-11years period. I used the addxy coordinates tool to locate the raingages in a map and using the feature to feature tool in arcmap converted the processed data in excel into a feature. I tried using the Spline approach to interpolate the erosivity values to cover the entire site, but what i am getting is not what i want. How do i improve it. I am attaching two maps for clarification

Comment: How do i attach a map??